# how to render content with react-bootstrap correctly?

Tags: html, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I have my html chunk below and I am expecting a result like this:

> row1
>
> 1item 1item 1item 1item
>
> row2
>
> 1item 1item 1item 1item

instead they stack up on eachother for some reason.

my html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="main" class="staticMain clearfix">      
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3>Table 1</h3>
                    <div class="topMargin row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="col-md-3"><span><i class="fas fa-user-tie iconSize"><span class="attendantName">Info</span></i>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><span><i class="fas fa-user-tie iconSize"><span class="attendantName">Info</span></i>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><span><i class="fas fa-user-tie iconSize"><span class="attendantName">Info</span></i>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><span><i class="fas fa-user-tie iconSize"><span class="attendantName">Info</span></i>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="topMargin row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="col-md-3"><span><i class="fas fa-user-tie iconSize"><span class="attendantName">Info</span></i>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><span><i class="fas fa-user-tie iconSize"><span class="attendantName">Info</span></i>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><span><i class="fas fa-user-tie iconSize"><span class="attendantName">Info</span></i>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><span><i class="fas fa-user-tie iconSize"><span class="attendantName">Info</span></i>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the result can be seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/evwsqmfz/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your divs of `<div class="col-md-12">` should be where you have your row.

Try replacing

```
<div class="topMargin row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
```

with

```
<div class="topMargin">
    <div class="row">
```

Having several columns inside another column won't work correctly unless those columns are wrapped in a `<div class="row">`

Answer (score -2):

Try class col-sm-3 on your column divs, the JS Fiddle preview area is very narrow ... also the parent div of columns needs class "row"

Comment: Just curious have you tried with your suggestion? I’ve tried adding sm, xs and md all together and still gave me the same result.

Comment: Oops I also added class "row" to the column's parent div

Answer (score -2):

All of the `div`s inside of `col-md-12` should be `span` instead. A div creates a newline, a span will try to stay on the same line.